# signing in mozilla firefox using pkcs#11 library

Tags: c++, firefox, cryptography, firefox-addon, pkcs#11

how can we sign in "Mozilla Firefox" browser using "Pkcs#11" library module?
using "Mozilla Addin" we should load jss42.jar, which is not available for download and when using jss33.jar, error message is displayed as "corrupted file- so cannot load addin".
can anybody help me in this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32755314/3325704

Comment: I recall someone was using js-ctypes to tap into some of this stuff. I'll dig around.

Comment: I found the guys name his name was @nona Ill look around if i can find his open source work to share with you. But I recall he was using js-ctypes along with `let secmodDB = Cc["@mozilla.org/security/pkcs11moduledb;1"]`

Comment: Ok found a topic he started on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31064708/1828637 I asked him for his code, you should comment there asking as well. Hopefully he'll share soon.